# Is this an ordinal transform?

Tags: code-golf, math, array, decision-problem, integer

Related: [What's my telephone number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/198237) which asks to calculate the terms of [A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085), the number of possible ordinal transforms of length n.

### Background

**[Ordinal transform](https://oeis.org/wiki/Ordinal_transform)** is a transformation on an integer sequence. For a sequence \$a=(a_0, a_1, a_2, \cdots)\$, the \$n\$-th term of the ordinal transform \$ord(a)_n\$ is defined as the occurrence count of \$a_n\$ in \$a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n\$. Informally, \$ord(a)\$ can be described as "the value \$a_n\$ appears the \$ord(a)_n\$-th time in the sequence \$a\$".

For example, the sequence `[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1]` transforms into `[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4]`.

```
1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1
1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4
^     ^  ^              ^
|     |  |              4th occurrence of 1
|     |  3rd occurrence of 1
|     2nd occurrence of 1
1st occurrence of 1
```

The number of possible ordinal transforms is [A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085). A hint to tackle this problem can be found on the page (search for "ballot sequences").

### Challenge

Given a non-empty finite integer sequence, test if it can be the result of ordinal transform of some integer sequence.

You can assume the input entirely consists of positive integers.

For output, you can choose to

1. output truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed), or
2. use two distinct, fixed values to represent true (affirmative) or false (negative) respectively.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

**Truthy**

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```

**Falsy**

```
[2]
[6]
[1, 3]
[2, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Does this work out to the same as [stackable sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/144201/20260) with 1-indexing?

Comment: @xnor Turns out to be yes. Another difference is that the sequence contents are not upper-bounded, though I guess it's minor...

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of the challenge linked by @xnor - I believe that the differences between the two are minor, as shown by [my answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231388/66833) to [both](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231393/66833)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
Ṭ€+\I’Ȧ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzjWPmtZox3g@aph5Ytn/w@1HJz3cOUMFKAZE7v//R0dzRRvG6gAJHQUYbaSjYIzgQQSMEHIoJIoWEx0FUx0FMx0FcxS9xkgMIGmCLmkCM9AYbmasDtBdYDvNoKqNQTREGZKlGE4wQneQCao0VL25DkhhbCwA)

-1 byte [thanks to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231386/is-this-an-ordinal-transform/231388?noredirect=1#comment530224_231388) [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)

Outputs an empty array (falsey) if it can be the result, and a non-empty array (truthy) if not.

### How it works

```
Ṭ€+\I’Ȧ - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
 €      - For each integer I in L:
Ṭ       -   Untruth; Generate a list of zeroes of length I, replace the last with 1
   \    - Scan by:
  +     -   Addition
    I   - Get the forward differences of each
     ’  - Decrement
      Ȧ - This array does not contain any 0s
```

For exactly what this does, let's look at this step by step:

| Command | Truthy example | Falsey example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Start | `[1, 2, 3, 1]` | `[1, 2, 3, 2]` |
| `Ṭ€` | `[[1], [0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1]]` | `[[1], [0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1]]` |
| `+\` | `[[1], [1]+[0,1], [1]+[0,1]+[0,0,1], [1]+[0,1]+[0,0,1]+[1]]` `[[1], [1,1], [1,1,1], [2,1,1]]` | `[[1], [1]+[0,1], [1]+[0,1]+[0,0,1], [1]+[0,1]+[0,0,1]+[0,1]]` `[[1], [1,1], [1,1,1], [1,2,1]]` |

At this point, we have running counts of each element. The `i`th element of `Ṭ€+\` is a list `[a,b,c,...,z]` where `a` is the number of counts of `1` in the first `i` elements of the input, `b` the counts of `2` and so on. The input is only truthy if each list is ordered descendingly.

In order to do this, we get the forward differences of each. This will be a list of lists of `-1`, `1` and `0`. If any of the differences have `1`, then it's ascending. We then decrement, mapping `1` to `0` and everything else to a non-zero element. Finally, we check with `Ȧ` that there are no zeroes in the list at any level.

Comment: I've definitely been thinking of something involving `Ṣ€Ƒ` myself, if that gets you marginally more confident

Comment: Looks correct to me. Interesting that Jelly doesn't have non-vectorizing cumulative sum built-in :P

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzjWPmtZox3gGuf0/3H500sOdM1SAAkDk/v9/dDRXtGGsDpDQUYDRRjoKxggeRMAIIYdComgx0VEw1VEw01EwR9FrjMQAkibokiYwA43hZsbqAN0FttMMqtoYREOUIVmK4QQjdAeZoEpD1ZvrgBTGxgIA) using the truthy/falsey in your language option, `I` to take forward-differences and `R` to force `0` and `-n` to empty lists and `+n` to `[1..n]`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's brilliant, thanks!

Comment: I really like this table method of explanation.  I'll probably be stealing that at some point.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.every(n=>a[a[~n]=-~a[~n],-n]--|n<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LDoIwELz3K/ZIk5bEFvGA5eZXNBwaLD5iWkMbEqPy64ggTy8z253Zne5VVcrl5eXuqbFH3RSiUSJVoa50@QhMW0ola5MJWndMqMkofZk9w43XzufKaQcCJJKbjLRAYGBGgE@vvsEmbYGLkYjAlkBMYLeY5bOixWgtRsNCPu5EsguMf1b@5d4zS/zLZ@vfREu592dovD8sbHlQ@TnwIFJ4IoDcGmdvOrzZU1AEHuMEvXHSfAA)

Ungolfed:

```javascript
arr => {
  const count = [Infinity]
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const num = arr[i];
    count[num] = (count[num] || 0) + 1;
    count[num - 1] = (count[num - 1] || 0) - 1;
    if (count[num - 1] < 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

<s>Quite exhausted so I'm sure I'll improve upon it in the morn'. Less sure that it's actually correct so, mods, please delete if it's not.</s> Shockingly, it *was* correct! Haven't been able to improve much on my score, though.

```
e1g2Æ=¡YôgU è¶X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ZTFnMsY9oVn0Z1Ug6LZY&input=WzEsIDEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDIsIDEsIDMsIDIsIDFd) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ZTFnMsY9oVn0Z1Ug6LZY&input=WwpbMV0KWzEsIDFdClsxLCAyLCAzLCAxXQpbMSwgMSwgMiwgMl0KWzEsIDIsIDEsIDIsIDEsIDIsIDFdClsxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA1LCA2LCA3XQpbMSwgMSwgMiwgMywgMSwgMiwgMywgMiwgNF0KWzEsIDEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDIsIDEsIDMsIDIsIDFdClsyXQpbNl0KWzEsIDNdClsyLCAxLCAxXQpbMSwgMiwgMiwgMV0KWzEsIDIsIDMsIDJdClsxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA0XQpbMSwgMiwgMywgMiwgMV0KXS1tUg)